# ¿Cómo puedo hacer la resta entre 2 array con js?

Tags: javascript

el problema es el siguiente:
tengo 2 `array` que obtengo de forma automática, los cuales debo hacer la resta entre el primero con el segundo pero por posición ejemplo:

```js
var array1 = [9,8,7,6,5]
var array2 = [10,20,30,40,50]
     //       (9-10),(8-20).......

/* objetivo
var array_resta = [-1,-12,-23,-34,-45]*/

//lo que había hecho yo era, meter los 2 array en otro array algo así :

var receptor = new Array();
receptor.push(array1)
receptor.push(array2)

// receptor = [[9,8,7,6,5],[10,20,30,40,50]]
// para luego intentar restar algo así:

let a_resta = new Array();
for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    let resta = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < receptor.length; i++) {
        // if (receptor[i][j] > 0) { //esto solo es una condicion por si uno de los array es de > length
            resta -= receptor[i][j];
        // }
    }
    a_resta.push(resta);
    }
    console.log(a_resta);

// lo unico que hace es hacer la suma y mostrar en negativo(-)
```

Bueno entonces, esto es lo que tengo estoy en blanco, no se si es buena idea hacer lo de "meter" en un `array` "general" para intentar hacer lo que necesito.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te recomiendo que uses la función [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) del *Array prototype* (del *build-in* de *Vanilla JavaScript*).

La función `reduce` es una propiedad, por tanto, de cada *array*. Toma como primer argumento una *callback* que se ejecutará por cada elemento del *array* y, opcionalmente, un valor inicial.

En tu caso, tu función debe retornar un *array* con la resta de los elementos. Por ello, el valor inicial que pasaremos como argumento será un *array* vacío, `[]`, al cual vamos a ir metiendo el resultado de las restas.

La *callback* que toma por argumento la función `reduce` recibirá el valor acumulado (en nuestro caso será el *array* resultado), el elemento actual de la iteración y, opcionalmente, el índice y el *array* original.

```
const first = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5];
const second = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];

const substract = (first, second) =>
    first.reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
        // acc es el array resultado
        // curr es el elemento actual
        // i es el indice del elemento actual

        // Camculamos el elemento de la resta
        const sub = curr - second[i];

        // Añadimos el elemento al array resultado
        acc.push(sub);

        // Devolvemos el array resultado
        // que será el mismo que nos pasarán
        // por algumento en la siguiente
        // iteración
        return acc;
    }, []);

console.log(substract(first, second)); // [ -1, -12, -23, -34, -45 ]
console.log(substract(second, first)); // [ 1, 12, 23, 34, 45 ]
```

El código realmente se puede reducir drásticamente usando el *spread operator*.

```
const substract = (first, second) =>
    first.reduce((acc, curr, i) => [...acc, curr - second[i]], []);
```

En la misma resta puedes añadir la lógica de qué pasa cuando estos dos *array* no tienen la misma longitud. También debes tenerlo en cuenta en el order el cual pases los *arrays* a la misma función.

**EDIT:** Extender el caso de dos *array* con longitud diferente.

Primero, añadamos una capa de abstracción a la función,

```
const merge = (first, second, operation) =>
    first.reduce((acc, curr, i) => [...acc, operation(curr, second[i])], []);
```

`merge` va a resultar un *array* basado en dos *array* pasados por argumento. El parámetro `operation` será el encargado del cálculo y la lógica de cada elemento basado en los dos elementos en una misma posición de ambos *array*.

Con eso, refactorizamos la función de antes sin tener en cuenta que dos *array* puedan tener diferente tamaño.

```
const substractSameLength = (first, second) => 
    merge(first, second, (op1, op2) => op1 - op2);
```

Con la abstracción, podemos definir varias formas de conseguir la función `substract`.

```
const substractDiffLength = (first, second) => {
    // Definimos la operación
    // op1 nunca será undefined
    const operation = (op1, op2) => op2 ? op1 - op2 : op1;

    // Calculamos cuál es el array de mayor tamaño
    // para invocar la función merge
    // con el orden correcto de parámetros
    const max = Math.max(first.length, second.length);
    return first.length === max
            ? merge(first, second, operation)
            : merge(second, first, operation);
}
```

En este caso, las posiciones del *array* más pequeño serán solo rellenas con el elemento del *array* más grande en esa posición.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: si me funciona perfecto, gracias!

Answer (score 4):

```js
var array1 = [9,8,7,6,5]
var array2 = [10,20,30,40,50]
 
const res = array2.map((r, i)=> array1[i] ? array1[i] - r : r);
console.log(res);
```

Primero iteramos por cualquiera de los dos arrays (siendo que ambos deberían tener la misma longitud) y luego vamos transformando valores mediante `map`, siendo `r` el elemento actual del array recorrido e `i` el indice numerico, por lo cuál si existen numeros a comparar restamos `array1[i] - r` lo cuál es justo lo que necesitas, en caso de que los arrays difieran en tamaño nos aseguramos de tener un respaldo, haciendo que el valor resultado sea el del segundo array sin restar.

Comment: `map` también es totalmente válido. +1

Comment: "Primero iteramos por cualquiera de los dos `arrays` (siendo que ambos deberían tener la misma longitud)" exacto, pero podrían no ser iguales en longitud, en ese caso que se podría hacer ? Gracias.

Comment: de igual forma si me ayuda a lo que necesito, muchas gracias.

Comment: En caso de que no sean del mismo tamaño deberas comparar cual tiene mayor tamaño primero para posteriormente usarlo tal cual en el código, puesto que el código fue hecho para que respalde aquello que no existe en el primer array, por lo cuál si un valor no existe en el array mas corto, entonces lo que hace es tomar el valor del segundo y no restarle nada, de esta manera nunca se produce un error.